# Do changes in SQLite automatically get reflected in MySQL?

Tags: android, mysql, service, sqlite

I am new to using services. In my application I want to run services in the background. I am creating the same database in MySQL server and SQLite. If I change some data in a table in the SQLite database, does it mean it should automatically store the change in the MySQL-server also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: **no**, it does not automatically reflect the changes made in SQLite into MySQL.

Why? Because you basically have 2 different databases, although they have the same name (and probably structure). In order for them to communicate and get synchronized, you need to implement some kind of communicating mechanism.

As suggested to you by *eggyal* in an above comment, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511402/how-to-sync-sqlite-database-on-android-phone-with-mysql-database-on-server), as a solution for this kind of problem is explained there.