# How to copy SQLite database from Android to a MySQL database (replicate/sync)

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, synchronization

I am building an Android app which will take some data and images from user and store them in a local SQLite DB. What I am looking for is a way by which I can replicate this DB to a MySQL DB on my server.

I looked on the Internet for the answer but there isn't a proper solution to it. Though the most common answers I found were SymmetricDB and setting up a web service. I am still confused which route to take.

The SQLite DB may also at need, have to pull updated data from the MYSQL DB, so I guess the better word to use is Sync rather than Replicate.

Answer (score 8):

Yes of course, its **Sync**.

You have to create `Web Service` for that.

#### Just follow some steps for sending data from **Android to MySQL**:

1. Create `JSON` object of your data using `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` class.
2. post that as an string to your `Web Service` that might be in `PHP` or whatever you prefered.
3. process to parse json and insert data in to `MySQL` database.

#### Same as from **MySQL to Android**:

1. Create `Web Service` that displays your data in `JSON` Format.
2. then you have to Request to that link and you'll get JSON data, just you have to parse and store into SQLite.

You have to take care about **Data Confiction.** for that you have to take one that store some value both side like *last sync date/time*.

#### There are some tutorial that will help for android JSON Parsing and `PHP JSON Parsing`.

1. [For Android](http://www.pratikbutani.com/2016/05/android-tutorial-json-parsing-using-retrofit-part-1/)
2. [For PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php)

If there is any problem then you can free to ping.

Happy Syncing.

Thank you.

Comment: "You have to take care about Data Confiction"  Indeed. It can take, let's say, five man-years of work to create a complete offline-online sync system.  ie, what say realm.io or zumero does.

Comment: Anyone reading this, do not take the two-way synchronization problem lightly. It starts with "I just need to fetch records from DB" and ends with a mess. if you are changing data at both ends, sync will have lot of hairy problems.