# sync data to server android

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm new to android sync so I really need ideas to get started. Actually my app's requirement is like this: My app needs to connect to my database online. But my android app can be used offline meaning, the user can add records to a local db, say sqlite. And then when the user connects to the Internet, the app should automatically connect to the server and add the record the user added when he is not online. Can you give me some considerations and ideas on how to do this? I really need your help guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend you to go for Sync Adapter. See these links

[AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html) and [Creating Sync Adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html).

I have used them long time ago. I will say that it is the best approach for syncing data between device and server. Usually, email apps use these sync adapters.

Sample is also given there. Download it if you want to go deep inside of "HOW".

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run background service like android alarm manager. You need to check that device is connected via internet or not. if device is connected via internet then sync the data to server.

Check this like to the way of data sync

[How to sync SQLite database on Android phone with MySQL database on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511402/how-to-sync-sqlite-database-on-android-phone-with-mysql-database-on-server)

Thanks