# Android application remote database syncing

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I am developing an Android application where users will see lists of Groups and join `1-*` Groups. Within the Groups will be members and users can message each other within the group they have joined. Sending messages 1 person to many and reply all.

I want this to support multiple devices. So, if i join a group and someone sends me a message, i want to see that message on my phone and tablet. If both have the app installed.

I want the user to be able to see group details while offline.

I have been doing some research and drawing diagrams on how this could work.

**What are my options for how to set this up with a remote database?**

Here are a couple of the options that i have finally narrowed down to.

1. Have the remote DB store everything. Have a local DB on the device that reflects the remote DB. Have the remote DB contain a version number. At some point, either scheduled or triggered, the app compares the version numbers in the local and remote and if the local is out of date it will update to the current remote DB.
2. Have the remote DB store everything. Have a local DB on the device that reflects everything in the remote DB except the messaging system. This would behave similar to #1. Except the tables and stuff that are related to the messaging system would "somehow, gcm maybe" send a message to all devices associated with the user that a message relating to the user has changed and the app will then update to the most recent version of the remote messaging tables in the remote database. Then their local database contains the new data and their "message box" would be updated.

What would be the best way to do this? How is this done currently in most systems? Are there more options then what i listed?

Remote DB: MySql

Local DB: sqlite

I am aware of some similar questions [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511402/how-to-sync-sqlite-database-on-android-phone-with-mysql-database-on-server), but i am wanting to know if either of these options or something else would be best for my specific scenario. Mainly how to handle the messaging part.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Option 1 is a pretty standard way of handling this problem.

A DB version # could work, but if it changes frequently you will end up resync all the data very often. Its probably better if you just store "Last Modified Date" on records and only pull down things that have changed since the last sync. That way you can return a smaller set of new records.

You would only want to pull down public information (the groups) and the information specific to the user.  The remote DB would have everything, but the local DB would only consist of data that is related to the user.

I found [this tutorial](http://android.programmerguru.com/how-to-sync-sqlite-on-android-to-mysql-db/) that walks through how this might be implemented using php on the remote server for API access.  You could streamline this process by using an ORM or "Out of the Box" API solution.

I'm sure there are more elegant solutions out there for syncing a local Android DB with a remote but this is likely the most practical approach for the non-enterprise solutions.